# Finding the maximum clique in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I've been recently trying to port maximum clique algorithm to python, yet I can not seem to implement it correctly. The goal is to find the largest clique, present in the graph. My aim is the implementation, stated in [this](http://insilab.org/articles/match2007.pdf) article, Figure 1 (the simple variation). My current code looks like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import operator

if __name__ == "__main__":


    ## read the graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edge(1,2)
    G.add_edge(1,3)
    G.add_edge(3,2)
    G.add_edge(3,4)


    C = nx.coloring.greedy_color(G, strategy=nx.coloring.strategy_largest_first)
    R = G.nodes()

    qu = []
    qmax = []    

    def maxClique(R,C,qu,qmax):

        while len(R) > 0:
            cdict= sorted(C.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
            pivot = cdict[0][0]
            color = cdict[0][1]
            R.remove(pivot)

            if len(set(qu)) + int(color) > len(set(qmax)):
                qu.append(pivot)
                neighbours = G.neighbors(pivot)                
                intersection = [x for x in R if x in neighbours]

                if len(intersection) > 0:
                    subgraph = G.subgraph(intersection)
                    Cx = nx.coloring.greedy_color(subgraph, strategy=nx.coloring.strategy_largest_first)
                    maxClique(intersection,Cx,list(set(qu)),qmax)

                elif len(qu) > len(qmax):
                    qmax = qu
                    qu = qu.remove(pivot)

                else:
                    return qmax

    print(maxClique(R,C,qu,qmax))
```

The algorithm must thus identify the {1,2,3} as the max-clique.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using networkx's [max clique](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.max_clique.html?highlight=max_clique#networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.max_clique) algorithm?

Comment: and can you say what is going wrong?

Comment: The problem was with the coloring, I misunderstood the algorithm.

Comment: @Joel Note that NetworkX's algorithm seem to be an approximation algorithm